# Jenkins 'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: flutter, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

When i created Jenkins Pipeline with below code its not loading system environment variables

Please give me the suggestion

```
pipeline {

  agent any
environment {

    PATH = "C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32"

}
    stages {
        stage('build'){
            steps{
                dir('app'){
       bat label: '', script: 'flutter build apk --release'
                }
        }}


        stage('DISTRIBUTE') {
            steps {
        appCenter apiToken: "APKKEY", 
        appName: 'sampleApp',
        distributionGroups: 'Test', 
        notifyTesters: false, 
        ownerName: 'sample', 
        pathToApp: 'app\\build\\app\\outputs\\apk\\release\\app-release.apk', 
        releaseNotes: '$BUILD_NUMBER'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error log 
**Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
        [Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
        [Pipeline] node
        Running on Jenkins in F:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\APK
        [Pipeline] {
        [Pipeline] withEnv
        [Pipeline] {
        [Pipeline] stage
        [Pipeline] { (build)
        [Pipeline] dir
        Running in F:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\APK\app
        [Pipeline] {
        [Pipeline] bat

```
    F:\Program Files\Jenkins\workspace\APK\app>flutter build apk --release 
    'flutter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // dir
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] stage
    [Pipeline] { (DISTRIBUTE)
    Stage "DISTRIBUTE" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // stage
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // withEnv
    [Pipeline] }
    [Pipeline] // node
    [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
    ERROR: script returned exit code 1
    Finished: FAILURE**
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add flutter to the PATH? if you can't run flutter in the terminal, it's more likely Jenkins can't too.

https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path